Discrepancy between pip and Poetry file
I'm currently trying to install PyTorch and PyTorch-XLA using a Poetry file but am finding out that it doesn't work. However, when I try to install the packages via pip it does. I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work for my Poetry configuration.
The pip command that I'm running is taken from the official PyTorch-XLA repository:
pip install torch~=2.2.0 torch_xla[tpu]~=2.2.0 -f https://storage.googleapis.com/libtpu-releases/index.html

My pyproject.toml file looks like this:
[tool.poetry]
name = "xla-test"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["John Doe"]
readme = "README.md"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "libtpu"
url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/libtpu-releases/index.html"
priority = "supplemental"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
datasets = "^2.18.0"
torch = { url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118/torch-2.2.0%2Bcu118-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl" }
torch_xla = { version = "~2.2.0", extras = ["tpu"], source = "libtpu" }

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

When I run poetry install I get the following error message:
Repository "libtpu" does not exist.

When I try to change the priorty of libtpu to being primary rather than supplemental, Poetry complains that it can't find a compatible version of datasets, which I'm assuming means that it's not searching PyPI.
When I try to add PyPI explicitly as a supplemental source, Poetry complains that libtpu doesn't exist.
Is Poetry not appropriate for this, or am I doing something wrong?
